# How to select a <p> tag in HTML/Angular

Tags: html, angularjs

I am currently trying to implement a selectable listview but am running into a few issues.  I am trying to use [ui-listview](https://github.com/StevenLambion/ui-listView), an angular add-on of sorts, but want to (1) highlight the < p > tag that the user clicks on, and (2) get this string into an angular variable. Is there a way to do this, or a different implementation of a listview that allows this?

```
<div class="panel-body" padding:0>
    <div class="ui-list-view-striped" ui-list-view="contact in contacts | orderBy:'Project' | filter:search">
        <p class="name">{{ contact.ListView }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `ng-click` and `ng-class`. Update data model by passing in contact object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you modify the objects in your `contacts` list? If so, you can add a `selected` boolean attribute to them that can be fired by an `ng-click` event over every `<p>` element. Then you can use that `selected` attribute in an `ng-class` to set a style marking the element as selected. Ej:

**html:**

```
<div class="panel-body" padding:0>
    <div class="ui-list-view-striped" ui-list-view="contact in contacts | orderBy:'Project' | filter:search">
        <p class="name" ng-class="{'css-selected': contact.selected}"><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="markSelected(contact)">{{ contact.ListView }}</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**javascript:**

in your controller:

```
yourController.markSelected = function(contact) {
  contacts.map(function(c) { c.selected = false; });
  contact.selected = true;
}
```

**css:**

```
.css-selected {
  /* your style for the selected element */
}
```